# Adding an exception to HTTP Auth for a range of IPs?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

We have a server which had HTTP Auth set on the root folder. Everyone must authenticate before they can hit any page on the server. We now have an external supplier who's software can't handle HTTP Auth but needs to be able to hit a URL on the server. Is is possible to add something to our config to allow only their IPs access to only one folder on our server, while leaving our global requirement for authentication in place?

Thanks,

Bart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is have something like:

```
<Directory /secure-area>
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
Satisfy Any 
</Directory>
```

Which will only ask for a password for people outside the allow range